Angular Material Select List Drop Down Arrow Position Not Right-hand but Middle
I have an odd situation where a deeply nested HTML segment of code may be inheriting some stylings from a parent that I can't predict or control. The widget is pretty straight forward...
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width-input" *ngIf="!isMultiSelect">
  <mat-label>{{ selectListForm.get('commonSettings').get('label')?.value }}</mat-label>
  <mat-select [value]="data?.state?.defaultValue">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options.controls" [value]="option.get('value')?.value">
      {{ option.get('label')?.value }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-hint class="custom-mat-hint">{{ selectListForm.get('commonSettings').get('suggestedText')?.value }}</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>

And the .scss stylings aren't that wild...
.preview-section {
  position: relative;

  mat-form-field {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }

  .custom-mat-hint {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 24px;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  }
}
.preview-title {
  color: #5c9edb; /* Light blue color */
  font-weight: bold; /* Make it bold for emphasis */
}
.preview-wrapper{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

But whenever the select list is greater than say 280px wide, the drop arrow on the right seems to hit a wall at say pixel 270 or so and stick there. So, if the object is 400px, the arrow looks like it is in the middle of the object rather than on the right side. Is this an internal Material limitation that can be overridden?


I am not able to reproduce this. Can you maybe setup a StackBlitz? What immediately caught my attention was the display: block you added to the Material components. You can safely apply this for your own components, but you should never apply this to third party components, it can easily mess up the layout. Does it work when you remove the display: block?

Change your custom class "full-width-input" to "mat-mdc-form-field-infix" because it is the default class for mat-form-field. This will allow you to adjust the mat-label width if needed. Additionally, the mat-select arrow will also be properly aligned with the mat-label.
Html file:
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="mat-mdc-form-field-infix">
  <mat-label>Your Label</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option value="one">First option</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="two">Second option</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

Css file:
.mat-mdc-form-field-infix {
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  width: 330px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


This is some better! Thank you. It's interesting because the 330px you suggest seems to be a limit... it moved it some to the right... like now it is 3/4 of the way there and looks better than in the middle. But there is still some white space to the right of it. When I increased the 330 to something larger, like 340 or 350, it seems to stay where it is with 330. But if i go much higher like 450, it actually starts to move back to left. Very odd behavior, but this is some better! Thanks. I upvoted your solution because it helped some.

@AppDreamer, Could you please share your TS file? I tried setting the label to 450px, and it worked well for me. If you share the TS file, it will help me solve the problem.
